# How can an SDP answer communicate it doesn't support ICE renomination?

Tags: webrtc, ice

The offer contains `ice-options:trickle renomination`. My understanding is:

1. `trickle` - trickle ICE
2. `renomination` - is renominating another higher priority pair after one has already been picked as active.

If the `answerer` does **not** support renomination, how can it let the `offerer` know that it should not renominate another pair?

Long story short - i'm investigating an SSRC timeout and I believe its due to the remote side renominating a pair when the local side does not support it. I stripped renomination out of the answer but I think its still renominating.

- OFFER: `ice-options:trickle renomination`
- ANSWER: no ICE options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving ice-options out should do the trick, the default value is false.
Check the logs for this line: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/webrtc/p2p/base/p2p_transport_channel.cc;l=478;drc=3cc22c22d7637bc5604e8fef3b0882b51a762901

Comment: That was my understanding. There are no ice-options in the offer but the answer contains ice-options: renomination. It looks like the answering endpoint is not respecting the offer. Well, that’s problematic. I’ll have to see what the code says (which is a custom code base : /). Thanks Philipp.